# How to make bookmarked page show up in FireFox address bar search?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

Normally, when I start typing in FireFox's address bar, it starts matching and gives me the closest match on top.

For example, if I type "su", it will auto-match to superuser.com and also place it on top in the pull down menu.

However, my bookmarks do not get any special treatment.

The page that I bookmarked is https://mail.yahoo.com/b/?adblock=1

When I type "mail" or "yahoo" or even "mail.yahoo", only the regular links show up. I don't see my bookmarked yahoo link. I used to see a star next to link when there is a bookmarked match. But this is not happening anymore.

Currently running Firefox 82.0.2. Anyway to make my bookmarked page show up in address bar search ahead?

Comment: Do you have bookmarks checked in `about:preferences#privacy` under "Address Bar"?

Answer (score 1):

To view bookmarks in *Search*:

- Go to the *Options* menu.
- Select *Search*.
- Be sure *Bookmarks* is checked.
- Uncheck any item type you wish to reduce number of results displayed. Too many choices may push bookmarks down the list, out of sight.

[image: Use bookmarks in Search]

- To [*restrict* search results to *Bookmarks*](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/address-bar-autocomplete-firefox), start to end the search string with an asterisk separated by a space. For example, either of the following would only display the *Bookmarks* including the word "yahoo":

  ```
  * yaho

  yaho *
  ```

At one time, *userChrome.css* could be used to control the order of search items, e.g., putting bookmarks at the top of the list, but apparently, that no longer works.  [If anyone could explain how to do so in current versions of *Firefox*, after v. 81, it would be *greatly appreciated.)

There are ["buckets" with the items in the URL bar](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/968616), but it does not appear there's a way to promote *Bookmark* items to the top. *sigh*

Comment: You are on to something here. My Bookmarks checkbox is checked but my Browsing history is over shadowing my search result. Unfortunately, one of most useful feature of the search suggestion is search from my past history. I would rather not give up the history search over a single bookmarked site.

Comment: Change the name of bookmarks you use frequently, e.g. put in *q* or *z* or other unlikely characters, and search on the new name, e.g., *qyahoo.mail*